# CSS Stacking Logo Between Images

Tags: css

Wanted to ask of potential methods for this scenario I've been trying to work on. I have a gallery container of two images that takes up 50% of the available width of the container.

Goal is to have a Logo centered in the middle (where there is a gap between two images) and have it mobile responsive as well.

What I have in mind: using Z-Index to stack the Logo in the middle of the two images however what I've been looking up so far has unfortunately not been of much usage.

```css
#container {
  position: relative:
  max-width: 1700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .box {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="images/picture01.png" class="box">
  <img src="images/logo-center.png" class="box">
  <img src="images/picture02.png" class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: it would be usefull to also add the CSS you already tried. The way the question is now it looks like you want us to write the code for you. That is **NOT** what SO is for.

Comment: Apologies for that. My code so far has been uploaded in original question.

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` and `position:absolute` for the logo. 
something like this:

```html
<div id="container">
  <img style="width: 50%; float:left" src="https://static.bhphoto.com/images/images500x500/LEE_Filters_115R_Peacock_Blue_Color_Effect_1272910523000_688218.jpg" class="box">
  
  <img style="position:absolute;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;left: 0;right: 0;" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/200x200/2076.png" class="box">
  
  <img style="width: 50%;" src="https://static.bhphoto.com/images/images500x500/LEE_Filters_115R_Peacock_Blue_Color_Effect_1272910523000_688218.jpg" class="box">
</div>
```